# Memcached - Caching information that must be in synch with the DB

Tags: java, caching, asynchronous, memcached, block

I'm using [Memcached](http://memcached.org/) as a Caching System and [Spymemcached](http://code.google.com/p/spymemcached/) as a java client to store my Objects in the cache.

Memcached put()/delete() are asynchronous.
For particular objects I need that the state in the Cache reflect the status of the DB.
For these objects I'm thinking of blocking the Thread on the Future returned by the spyMemcachedClient.put() method to be sure that the cache reflect the current status of the DB.

something like

```
changedObject -> block on Memcached.put() Future .. once it's finished ->  writeToDB  = every subsequent Memcached.get() object is guaranteed to be in synch with the DB
```

If I don't synchronize and I hit the cache fast enough with a spyMemcachedClient.get() it might be that the object is not reflecting the current DB status.

I'm wondering if it's correct to block on the put() for few kind of Objects or if this will decrease dramatically my Cache System performance? 
Can I do something like that or I'm not really supposed to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you are using the cache wrong. You are assuming that put() actually succeeds in putting the data in the cache and that right after the blocking of the call to put() that the data you put in is the data you get back with get(). There are a few problems with this:

1. put() might fail (because of
   network error, out of memory error
   etc)
2. put() might succeed but the
   data you put in might be flushed
   because newer, more prioritized data
   need to be put in
3. another process
   might put() data, perhaps even old
   data in

... to name a few.

So basically you should be aware of concurrency and never rely on the cache. This is a acceptable and safe way of using the cache:

```
public String getArticleText(String uuid) {

 String cacheKey = "article_" + uuid;
 String text = cache.get(cacheKey);
 if (text == null) {

  text = fetch text from db...
  cache.put(cacheKey, text);
 }
}
```

Using this approach, you can make sure the cache has the latest version by simply removing the cache entry when updating the article text (in this example):

```
public void updateArticleText(String uuid, String text) {

 update article in db...
 cache.delete("article_" + uuid);
}
```

So basically, you put the data in to the cache at request time, not when the data is updated. Because what would happen if you update the article, then have to restart the cache server (in a distributed environment - very common for memcached)? Your cache would never be filled with data unless you update every single article on your system - which you probably very rarely do.

Ok, I hope this helps ;)

Comment: as I mentioned set/delete are asnychronous.. so I don't understand how delete can solve this problem if a get request against the cache is triggered before the actual delete takes place. as they are async. to me it looks like your solution has the same problem as setting the key with another object..

Comment: If you need the entry in the cache to be updated before your application execution can continue to function properly then it probably means that your application itself is depending on the data in the cache, which is the wrong way to do things. Why do you need to wait for the data to be deleted/set before you can continue?

Comment: My app is not depending on the data in the cache. I'm using the cache in the normal way but I'm wondering if I can still use it in an efficient way to store objects that should always be in synch with the DB status. It's vital for the application that very few object are in sync with the db. As put (or delete as you suggest) are asynch there is no way to guarantee this if I don't block until the actual operation takes place.

Comment: Ok. So if you need to block the thread until the delete operation is complete, then it means something in that same thread is using cache.get() to get the data? Or why do you need it to block to make sure it is in synch? Also, as I wrote you can not rely on the data existing in the cache at all - the only thing you can really rely on is that _sometime_ after you call cache.delete() that entry gets deleted form the cache.

Comment: For article text it's fine if they are not in synch with the DB I don't care.. but for other objects I need them to be in synch. With your solution if I have the article text in cache and then I update it using updateArticleText and than I'm fast enough to hit the cache again (before the actual delete is executed) I'll get the old text for the article. In this case we can say that's ok, we don't care as it's just an article description.. but I'm talking of a solution when the returned info needs to be in synch with the DB all the times

Comment: Ok, then perhaps the usage of memcache is not appropriate in this situation. If the asynchronous nature of memcache is a limitation perhaps you should focus on optimizing the cache of your database server instead? Blocking a thread to wait for memcache sounds like a real bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. As far as I understand, another Thread can call cache.get() with the same key while delete() has still to be executed. let's say updateXXX has updated the DB with values used by other some other service and the cached object is still out of synch. Another Thread access the cache with the same key and gets the out of synch object and then gets some other objects from the DB. Some of the data in the object returned from the cache doesn't reflect the others returned from the DB... I don't know how to explain it better..

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I was wondering if using memcached and blocking was still a good solution for very few objects that must be in synch all the time

Comment: Yes, this is a common concurrency problem with multi-threaded applications and not solved easily.